# In Deployment Monitoring Tool, why do I receive the message "DT cannot be empty" when clicking on a specific deployment?

Tags: deployment, sccm, sccm-2012-r2

When clicking on the top deployment in the screenshot below, the message "DT cannot be empty" is displayed and the Deployment Monitoring Tool closes.  Clicking on other deployments shows the expected information in the info pane.  I have not been able to find very much information about this issue.

I presume DT stands for Deployment Type.

I am unsure if this message is evidence of an actual problem with the deployment.

Here is what I know:

- The issue occurs on many different clients and possibly all clients.
- The deployment is assigned to a collection which contains a little over 200 members.
- The deployment's availability and deadline schedules are different and both are in the future.  They are based on UTC time.
- This is for an Application, with a Script Installer Deployment Type.
- The action is Install and the purpose is Required.
- I was able to replicate the issue with a brand new deployment of a completely different application.
- The deployment appears to proceed as scheduled.  Once the deployment comes Available, the issue no longer occurs and I can view the details of the Deployment from the client as expected.
- If I change the "Available" time to some time in the past, the issue goes away.  If I then set the time back to some time in the future, the issue does NOT come back, but the client shows (DMT) and acts like (Software Center) the Available time is in the future.

Any assistance or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I will edit this question as I get more information and I will also post the answer if I come to it on my own.  I can't be the only person out here experiencing the issue.

[image: DT cannot be empty]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell at this point, the issue has something to do with the Available time being set to something in the future when the client first receives the assignment.

If I set the Available time to some time in the past and let the client receive the assignment, then set the Available time in the future, the issue goes away.

The deployment proceeds as scheduled.

Comment: I am posting this as the answer right now, but if someone has more of an explanation I would gladly reassign the answer.